Laravel Pest calls artisan test to a member function connection() on null
some people around that can help me with testing with Pest and Laravel 11?
namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\Agenda;
use function Spatie\RouteTesting\routeTesting;

routeTesting('all api routes')
    ->include('api/*')
    ->bind('agenda', Agenda::factory()->create())
    ->assertSuccessful();

And when running: php artisan test
I get this:    ERROR  Call to a member function connection() on null
This is my tests/Pest.php file:
uses(
    Tests\TestCase::class,
    RefreshDatabase::class,
)->beforeEach(function () {
    Artisan::call('migrate --force');
})->in('Feature');

The script that fails is located at tests/Feature/RouteApiTest.php
The .env.testing contains:
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=:memory:
APP_DEBUG=true

What am I missing?

Is there a problem if you remove the Artisan::call() in  the beforeEach ?

@xenooooo nope. renamed it to $this->artisan('migrate'); without any luck either.

You generally don't need to call migrations during testing, I think that's what @xenooooo was getting at.
What does your Tests\TestCase class look like? Does its setUp function include parent::setUp()?

@Diana you don't need to call migrations during testing if the RefreshDatabase::class is defined inside the uses(). I only asking if there's a need to use the Artisan::call() is that when using RefreshDatabase::class it only remove the data inside the table then add a new data but the id wil not reset to 1 so I was asking if there's a problem in that scenario ?

try this: ('migrate:fresh --seed')

but since this is with connection, before the test, do like: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;         // Check database connection         $this->assertNotNull(DB::connection());         dd(DB::connection()); check the factory too if is correct. add more logs if there is..

@user1469734 have u checked the comments?
